# Windows Japanese IME Toggling Automatically

Tags: input-languages, window-focus, ime

Currently, I'm typing into SuperUser in the Half-width Alphanumeric / Direct Input mode, and the window with focus is Firefox. However, if I give focus to Notepad where I was last using Hiragana mode, my mode immediately toggles to Hiragana again instead of staying put.

This is to say that my IME records the input mode I last used on any open window, and it will switch back to that mode whenever that window is refocused.

This runs counter to my idea of how IME mode switching should work: similarly to Caps-Lock, the toggle should be triggered only by me and maintain a constant state between window focuses.

How can I disable this automatic toggling?

Comment: In Windows: go to _Advanced keyboard settings_ and untick _Let me set a different input method for each app window_. (I deleted this my answer as it isn't useful for you).

Comment: After further testing I've found that if I tick this box, Windows toggles between my English and Japanese keyboards with window refocus. However, the box's state does not affect which Japanese input method I'm using, so my original problem stands.